# trying to search a key word and if exists replacing the whole line : getting error :io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

trying to replace whole line if it matches with specefic character but getting an error below as io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable

trying to replace if "date=datetime(" exists then replace the complete line (in the file) with something :  date=datetime(2020, 1, 1)

pls anyone suggest.

```
Sampledata: /home/arya/config.txt


/home/file.txt,date=datetime(2020, 1, 1)
/home/file2.txt,date=datetime(2020, 1, 20)




for variable in open("/home/arya/config.txt","r"):
    filename=variable.rstrip('\n').split(',')[0]
    replaceval=variable.rstrip('\n').split(',')[1]
    outFile = open(filename,'w')
    for line in outFile:
        if "date=datetime(" in line:
            line=replaceval
            outFile.write(line)

Error : io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable

content of /home/file.txt

import os 
date=datetime(2099, 1, 1) ## this value may change in each file 

trying to get something like below after replace 

import os 
date=datetime(2020, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`outfile` is being opened with the `'w'` flag, which means a new file is opened and there's nothing to iterate over.

```
for variable in open("/home/arya/config.txt", "r"):
    filename = variable.rstrip("\n").split(",")[0]
    replaceval = variable.rstrip("\n").split(",")[1]
    originalContents = open(filename, "r").readlines()
    outfile = open(filename, "w")
    for line in originalContents:
        if "date=datetime(" in line:
            line = replaceval
        outFile.write(line)
```

This will set the original contents to the variable `originalContents` using the `readlines()` method, this returns a list of all lines in the original file.

Then the same filename is opened with the `'w'` flag, which overwrites it.  The new contents are then written to it.  The contents of `line` are modified as needed.

Comment: Thanks Richard. But still i am getting an different error : "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: It's most likely this line:
   `replaceval=variable.rstrip('\n').split(',')[1]`

You may need to add a test to make sure that `variable` is properly populated first